# H264 Video + Speex Audio streaming through RTP?

Tags: c, streaming, rtp, libavcodec, libavformat

In my application,I successfully managed to encode/decode H264 video and Speex audio using libavcodec and save in MKV container
using libavformat.

Now instead of creating a container file , I want to stream audio and video over our local network.

I saw that RTP is the standarized way to do this.

According to libavformat sourcecode,it does not support Speex with RTP.

Any other suggestions on streaming H264/Speex over the LAN?

What things I should read before I implement Speex support in libavformat RTP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely read the RFC for the [speex RTP payload format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5574) (It is not clear from your post whether you know about the RFC). [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) covers RTP, and if you are new to RTP, I would suggest reading [Perkin's book](http://csperkins.org/standards/rtp-book.html).

Note that if you are only streaming to your own application, you can of course stream the speex any way you like: you do not have to use the standard. OTOH if you do implement the speex payload format, you could contribute it back to the open source community.